# javascript auto files listing in the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

is there anyway for example when i navigate to http://example.com/links/pages/index.html

i have 4 .html files in /pages directory with names page1.html , page2.html , page3.html , page4.html

then that index.html must show me a list of pages that is exist in this /pages directory? without i list them on index.html manually by myself. i only want them to be listed at index.html when ever i create a new page at /pages directory

here's some example hope it helps : http://plnkr.co/edit/kIiod2DR6zgSpmuUNsUi?p=preview

or this example

```
<!-- This is index.html page in this directory http://example.com/links/pages/index.html -->

<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- here must be listed pages that is exist in this directory /pages -->

    <!-- example for to be listed -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="page1.html">page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="page2.html">page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="page3.html">page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="page4.html">page 4</a></li>
    </ul>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: PhP function `scandir()` seems to feet your need (http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php).

Comment: It's possible but not when your page has the extension .html

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:
in folder "pages" you have:

- page1.html
- page2.html
- page3.html

index.php in root directory will be:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- here must be listed pages that is exist in this directory /pages -->

    <?php
        $dir = 'pages';
        $pages = array_values(array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.')));
    ?>

    <ul>
        <?php
            foreach ($pages as $page) {
                $name = str_replace('.html', '', $page);
                echo "<li><a href=\"$page\">$name</a></li>";
            }
        ?>
    </ul>

  </body>

</html>
```

the output will be:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>

    <ul>
       <li><a href="page1.html">page1</a></li>
       <li><a href="page2.html">page2</a></li>
       <li><a href="page3.html">page3</a></li>
    </ul>

  </body>

</html>
```